# html: construct link through multiple buttons

Tags: html, forms

I have a form which I want to link through to some pre constructed html pages that are constructed in a hierarchy such as:

```
           |Data1(DIR) -> file1,file2,file3
/var/www/  |  
           |Data2(DIR) -> file1,file2,file3
```

I want to be able to choose which directories files to view via a radio button (or equivalent) but I cant find how to do this. I have the form set up as follows with a radio button choice followed by a dropdown of the 7 files, where the ##option## is what I want to have replaced with the directory to open. I think I am going after this in a perl manner and not at all html-y. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
<form action="../cgi-bin/redirect.pl" method="post" onsubmit="return dropdown(this.gourl)">

<td><big>
    <input name="project" value="data1" type="radio"> Dataset1
    <input name="project" value="data2" type="radio"> Dataset2</big>
<br><br>
<select name="gourl"><option value="">Choose Taxonomy level... 
    </option><option value="##option##/superkingdom.html">Superkingdom
    </option><option value="##option##/phylum.html">Phylum
    </option><option value="##option##/class.html">Class
    </option><option value="##option##/order.html">Order
    </option><option value="##option##/family.html">Family
    </option><option value="##option##/genus.html">Genus
    </option><option value="##option##/species.html">Species
    </option></select>
<input value="Go" type="submit">
```

Comment: Think the action needs to change not the onsubmit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sorted it through php. Adding it here for any future people!

```
<?php
echo "<form>";
echo "<b>Select a Site:</b><br>";
$sites = glob("*");
foreach ($sites as $site) {
    print "<input name=\"$site\" type=\"radio\" value=\"$site\" onclick=\"submit()\">$site<br>";
}
echo "</form>";

foreach($_GET as $key=>$value) {
    $$key = $value;
    $return = $value;
    print "<b>site: $return</b>";

    print "<br><select id=\"setit\" name=\"url\">
           <option value=\"\">Choose Taxonomy level...</option>
           <option value=\"$return/superkingdom.html\">Superkingdom</option>
           <option value=\"$return/phylum.html\">Phylum</option>
           <option value=\"$return/class.html\">Class</option>
           <option value=\"$return/order.html\">Order</option>
           <option value=\"$return/family.html\">Family</option>
           <option value=\"$return/genus.html\">Genus</option>
           <option value=\"$return/species.html\">Species</option>
           </select>
           <input type=\"button\" value=\"go\"
    onclick=\"window.open(setit.options[setit.selectedIndex].value)\">";
}
?>
```